# Получить адрес корневой директории в git-репозитории

Tags: git, shell

Я пишу shell-скрипт для автоматизации работы с Git. Мне нужен способ получить полный или относительный адрес корневой директории проекта при выполнении команды в любой вложенной директории (включая корневую).

Например, структура проекта, лежащего в `Users/nickvolynkin/git-example`:

```
- root/
  | - .git/
  | - a/
  | - b/
  | - c/
      | - c1/
      | - c2/


cd c/c1/
echo somecommand

# вариант 1
../../

# вариант 2
Users/nickvolynkin/git-example
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Абсолютный путь через [rev-parse](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)**

```
$ echo $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
Users/nickvolynkin/git-example
```

**Относительный путь через rev-parse**

```
$ echo $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
../../
```

**Абсолютный путь через alias**

```
[alias]
    root = "!pwd"
```

в shell-скрипте:

```
$ cd Users/nickvolynkin/git-example/c/c1
$ echo `git root`
Users/nickvolynkin/git-example

# отличие от просто pwd:
$ pwd
Users/nickvolynkin/git-example/c/c1
```

**Абсолютный путь через временный alias (без регистрации <s>и смс</s>).**

```
$ echo $(git -c alias.root='!pwd' root)
```

**Для передачи аргументом в Git**

Если этот адрес необходимо передать аргументом в какую-то из команд Git, то лучше использовать `:/`

```
# из любой папки делает reset на всю рабочую область
$ git reset :/

# то же самое, что и 
$ git reset $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

<sub>Частично основано на ответах из [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957928/2790048)</sub>

Comment: если я всё правильно понимаю, то конструкция `echo $(git -c alias.root='!pwd' root)` полностью идентична команде `pwd`.

Comment: вероятно, имелос в виду, чтобы в алиасе `root` вместо `"!pwd"` использовать `"rev-parse --show-toplevel"`. примерно так (без изменения конфигурации): `git -c alias.root="rev-parse --show-toplevel" root`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: эта конструкция идентична только если запускать из корневой папки проекта. Только что проверил еще раз.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: а вот для alias это избыточно, т.к. оно и без него срабатывает отлично.

Comment: а! вот оно как. действительно, алиасы git выполняет, предварительно сделав cd в корень рабочей копии. круто. впервые обратил на это внимание.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да-да, в том и заключается трюк с pwd.