# Как получить исходный путь в скрипте, запускаемом через git alias

Tags: git, shell, git-alias

Если через Git alias запускается внешний процесс, то он выполняется из корня рабочей области (той, где обычно лежит .git/ и которая возвращается командой [`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438614/181472))

Что делать, если путь, из которого запускается alias, важен? Как запускаемый процесс может узнать, откуда был выполнен alias?

Comment: *из корневой директории* — корневой каталог находится не там. может быть, лучше: *из корня рабочей копии*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого запускаемому процессу доступна переменная окружения (environment variable) `GIT_PREFIX`.

Начиная с [Git 1.7.6](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.6.txt#L29-L31):

> Процессы, запущенные через "`[alias] <name> = !process`" могут использовать переменную окружения `GIT_PREFIX`

[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f9504c48ea59951a2aa3ee17e7c7fc36285e225/Documentation/config.txt#L762-L763):

> Переменной `GIT_PREFIX` присваивается значение, получаемое из выражения '`git rev-parse --show-prefix`', выполняемого в первоначальной текущей директории.

Обратите внимание, что `GIT_PREFIX` содержит относительный путь, т.е. от корня рабочей области до первоначальной директории. Если вы передаете это значение в команду Git, то этого как раз достаточно.

Если alias выполняется из корня рабочей области, то `GIT_PREFIX` не определена. Чтобы гарантированно получить валидный путь, лучше использовать ее с выражением `${GIT_PREFIX:-.}`: при запуске из корневой директории это выражение равно '`.`'

Пример использования из тестов Git, [`t/t1020-subdirectory.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/t/t1020-subdirectory.sh):

```sh
test_expect_success 'GIT_PREFIX for !alias' '
    printf "dir/" >expect &&
    (
        git config alias.test-alias-directory "!sh -c \"printf \$GIT_PREFIX\"" &&
        cd dir &&
        git test-alias-directory >../actual
    ) &&
    test_cmp expect actual
'
```

<sub>Это перевод ответа с [EN.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722425/2790048)</sub>